# Are credit cards (Master Card) widely accepted in Morocco (Fez, Marrakesh, Meknes, Ouarzazate)?

Tags: buses, payment-cards, restaurants, morocco, tourist-traps

I am traveling to Fez, Marrakesh, Meknes and Ouarzazate. I hold a Mastercard (German bank). Are such credit cards accepted in the museums and restaurants in these cities? When used in a restaurant, is there a minimum amount you have to spend in order to pay by credit card?

What about public transportation? Can I buy tickets for trains and buses (Supratours, CTM, ONCF) using Mastercard?

Or should I carry cash all the time?

Comment: Please come to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=travel.stackexchange.com) so we can talk about this question.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely have cash at all time. Bank cards can be used in a number of places, stores and restaurants alike but it's not a general rule. 
For example a well-known fried chicken restaurant does not accept it in at least two franchises I went to.

I am sure you won't be able to use your card to pay for a taxi, and I would recommend having cash handy for bus or train too.

There might be a minimal amount that should be around 100 and 150 dirhams.

Addendum : while in major cities, ATM are widely available, the same can't be said for smaller cities. Furthermore it has been my experience that some ATM might get empty on saturday night or sunday because cash is more widely used than any other mean of payment. Be prepared :)

Answer (score 3):

We visited Morocco a few months back. Credit cards are not generally excepted. Even in the restaurants (normal) credit cards are not accepted. ***It's better to keep enough cash with you.***

***ONCF definitely don't accept credit card*** (I had to buy tickets by cash several times). I guess CTM bus accept credit card at their counter.

The exchange rates also vary from place to place (tourist places, in general, provide poor exchange rate).

For better Information, please visit my channel:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJLzR83mYNw&list=PLeolEzFfNLHpWSNodeiy08a7JXCmzoshs